# multiplexer and demultiplexer ic

Tags: multiplexer, integrated-circuit

Is there a single IC that has both multiplexer and demultiplexer functions?

Comment: This is a shopping question, and off topic: a user is looking for a product that may not be available in the near future or be geographically limited. I suggest looking at parametric searches provided by DigiKey, Mouser, and other electronics distributors.

Comment: @tyblu - Not. I think as specified it's sufficiently broad to be interesting for many users and remain so.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a 'shopping' question, but I would regard it as overly vague since it doesn't indicate whether it's supposed to simultaneously multiplex one set of data and demultiplex another, whether the data to be demultiplexed will always be sent in a particular sequence, etc.

Comment: A PAL, PLA, or PLD would be quite good at this, if your concern is reducing chip count.

Answer (score 5):

An analog mux will do this.  It is bidirectional, so the same circuit will work as mux or demux depending on which end is driven.  The classic chip is the [CD4051](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets/208/109138_DS.pdf) but more modern parts will have better specs.

Comment: That's a single chip which can act like both, not a single chip that *contains* both.

Comment: The cd4052 then.